# How would you add a JArray into a JObject without adding a new JObject key/name?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net

using .NET C#, I am trying to create a new JObject from a JArray. I have a FetchData JObject that I want to return a JObject of data for data driven testing. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static JObject FetchData(string testMethodName)
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("PathToJsonfile"))
            {
                string jsonstring = r.ReadToEnd();
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
                JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(obj[testMethodName].ToString());

                JObject jObject = new JObject(new JProperty("test",jsonArray));

                return jObject;
            }

        }
```

I want to return a JObject of test data that pertains to the testMethod which is being run. when I run this code, jObject returns:

```
"test": [
    {
      "loginId": "testuser1",
      "userCase": "verify for user"
    },
    {
      "loginId": "testuser2",
      "userCase": "verify for user"
    }
  ]
```

My issue is that I only want to return the following arrays within the JObject:

```
{"loginId":"testuser1","userCase":"verify for user"}
```

I have researched for a while and cannot find a solution without adding a key to the new JObject, in this case, key being "test".

Is this even possible in C#?

I have also tried adding the JArray directly to the JObject:

```
JObject jObject = new JObject(new JObject(jsonArray));
```

but get error : System.ArgumentException: 'Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.json.Linq.JObject

I have also tried adding the arrays to the JObject like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.Count; i++)
                {
                    jObject[i] = jsonArray[i];
                }
```

but get error : System.ArgumentException : Set JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.

fwiw this is how I am doing this is Java and it works like a charm, but I cannot figure it out in C#. Java Code:

```
JSONObject[] jsonObject = new JSONObject[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            jsonObject[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        }
```

Comment: JArray.FromObject(myObject);

Comment: `{"loginId":"testuser1","userCase":"verify for user"}` is not an array it is an object. Can you clarify what exactly do you want to return - first element of json array? Or all elements as separate `JObject`s? Or just a `JArray`?

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, thanks for the response. I want to return a JObject of all elements as separate object like this: [{"loginId":"testuser1","userCase":"verify for user"},{"loginId":"testuser2","userCase":"verify for user"}]

Comment: That is not json object that is json array, so you need to change your return type to `JArray` and return `jsonArray`

Comment: You are right @GuruStron . I realize that I was not asking the right question now. I want to return a JObject of the first element of the array, like this: {"loginId":"testuser1","userCase":"verify for user"}, do you know how I would do that?

Comment: @GHDevOps thanks for the response. Where would I be implementing JArray.FromObject(myObject); ? I tried JObject jObject = new JObject(JArray.FromObject(jsonArray));  but this obviously did not work.

Comment: fwiw this is the solution in Java, but I cannot fogure it out in C#               :JSONObject[] jsonObject = new JSONObject[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            jsonObject[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get first element of array you can do next:

```cs
var json = @"{
""test"": [
    {
      ""loginId"": ""testuser1"",
      ""userCase"": ""verify for user""
    },
    {
      ""loginId"": ""testuser2"",
      ""userCase"": ""verify for user""
    }]
}";
var testMethodName = "test";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var first = (JObject)jObject[testMethodName][0]; // note that this can throw for multiple reasons
```

Analog of your java code would be:

```cs
// parse jObject as earlier
var jArr = (JArray)jObject[testMethodName];
var jsonObjectArr = new JObject[jArr.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < jArr.Count; i++)
{
    jsonObjectArr[i] = (JObject)jArr[i];
}
```

Or you can use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm):

```cs
// parse jObject as earlier
var jsonObjectArr = jObject[testMethodName]
    .Children<JObject>()
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return only the first object of your array like this:

```
public static JToken FetchOneDatum(string testMethodName)
{
  string jsonString = GetFileContent("sampleTest.txt");
  JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
  JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(obj[testMethodName].ToString());
  return jsonArray[0];
}
```

You can find the whole visual Studio solution here:
[solution on GitHub](https://github.com/fredatgithub/JsonParsing)

Answer (score 0):

C# approach ;)

```
public class Test
{
    public string loginId { get; set; }
    public string userCase { get; set; }
}

public class Scenario
{
    public Test[] tests { get; set; }
}

// Usage
public static Test FetchData(string testMethodName)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("PathToJsonfile"))
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var scenario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Scenario>(json);

        return scenario.tests.First();
    }
}
```