# How would you add all elements of a JArray to a JObject in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net, json.net

I am trying to add the elements of a `JArray` to a `JObject` in C#. I have the solution in Java, but cannot figure out how to do the same in C#. Here is my Java code:

```java
 public static JSONObject[] fetchData(String dataFile, String arrayName) {
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    try {
        jsonArray = extractObject_JSON(dataFile).getJSONArray(arrayName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If Method Name is not matching with arrayName, then default will be taken
        jsonArray = extractObject_JSON(dataFile).getJSONArray("default");
    }
    JSONObject[] jsonObject = new JSONObject[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        jsonObject[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

and here is my C# code:

```
public static JObject FetchData(string testMethodName)
{

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("PathToFile"))
    {
        string jsonstring = r.ReadToEnd();
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(obj[testMethodName].ToString());

        JObject jObject = new JObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.Count; i++)
        {
            jObject[i] = jsonArray[i];

        }

        return jObject;
    }

}
```

`jsonArray` in this code example returns:

```json
{[
  {
    "loginId": "testuser1",
    "userCase": "verify for user"
  },
  {
    "loginId": "testuser2",
    "userCase": "verify for user"
  }
]}
```

The `testMethodName` would be LoginTest_E2E (see .json input file below)

```json
   {
      "LoginTest_E2E": [
        {
          "loginId": "testuser1",
          "userCase": "verify for user"
        },
        {
          "loginId": "testuser2",
          "userCase": "verify for user"
        }
      ]
    }
```

When I run my C# code I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Set JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.'

I would like the `fetchData` method to return a `JObject` of:

```json
 { 
    "loginId": "testuser1",
    "userCase": "verify for user"
  },
  {
    "loginId": "testuser2",
    "userCase": "verify for user"
  }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this in C#?

Comment: I noticed that you've asked a [very similar looking question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841334/how-would-you-add-a-jarray-into-a-jobject-without-adding-a-new-jobject-key-name) two hours ago which didn't receive an answer. Is this post fundamentally different?

Comment: I don't think the end result you are expecting is a valid JSON. Arrays have indexes, objects have properties. considering you have that result how would you access the first element? You can't use an index, because it's not an array, there is no property name either. Maybe if you share the actual reason why would you want do this, you might get a more useful answer.

Comment: Also in the Java code you have an array of JsonObjects, in C# code you only have one JObject instance.

Comment: thanks @SelmanGenç I think that is where I am off course here as i want to replicate the Java code in C#. DO you know how I would create an array of jsonObjects in my C# example?

Comment: @SelmanGenç this fetchData method is going to be used to fetch data for a Data-driven NUnit test

Comment: @apg3253 just change the declaration of `JObject` to `JObject[]` so then you have an array of objects...

Answer (score -1):

As you have it written, jObject is expecting a string value for the key of the property you are adding to it. At least that's my understanding judging from the fact that JObject extends IDictionary<string, JToken>: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm

You're trying to give it an integer value as a key. Judging from your Java code, it looks like you meant to declare an array of JObjects, but you just declared one here:

> JObject jObject = new JObject();

If this is the case, change it to JObject[] as @Selman said.